# Visual Composer only shows a shortcode entered in the shortcode mapper

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

I'm using the Visual Composer Shortcoder Mapper. I have introduced 2 equal shortcodes, they show the same but in a different format. Shortcodes have different names but when adding those shortcodes on the page, only one of them appears.

Example:

```
 [Events_list limit="10" category="1"]<p>#_EVENTDATE<p>[/event_list]
 [Events_list limit="10" category="1"]<div>#_EVENTDATE</div>[/event_list]
```

Both shortcodes work, but only 1 of them appears. How can I fix this?

[image: Shortcode Mapper]
[image: Page editor]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I missed `wp_head()` in header and `wp_footer()` on footer. This worked for me.